# Why can't we use nested type through class-member-access expression?

Tags: c++, types

I'm trying to understand why we can't use nested type through class-member-access expression.
For instance, we have the following class:

```
struct U
{
    struct A
    {
        static int v;
        int a;
    };

    struct B
    {
       int b;
    };
};

U a;

typedef a.A T; //'a' does not name a type

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(a.A).hash_code(); //invalid use of 'struct U::A'
    struct a.A b;                         //trying to declare a variable of type U::A
                                          //error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
    a.A b;                                //the same as above
                                          //error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
    a.A.v = 5;                            //error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token
}
```

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1e74f1e1ec6ce6e)**

The Standard says:

Section `N3797::5.2.5/2 [expr.ref]`

> For the first option (dot) the first expression shall have complete
>   class type. For the second option (arrow) the first expression shall
>   have pointer to complete class type. The expression E1->E2 is
>   converted to the equivalent form (*(E1)).E2; the remainder of 5.2.5
>   will address only the first option (dot).In either case, the
>   *id-expression shall name a member of the class or of one of its base classes*.

Whereas, section `N3797::9.2/1 [class.mem]` gives a definition of class member:

> Members of a class are data members, member functions (9.3), nested
>   types, and enumerators.

So I can't see the restriction for such usage of nested type. Why not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look further down in [expr.ref]

> (4.4) If E2 is a nested type, the expression E1.E2 is ill-formed.

Comment: This is a clause under "*If E2 is declared to have type “reference to T,”*", I don't think this applies here.

Comment: @luk32 "If E2 is declared to have type “reference to T,” then E1.E2 is an lvalue; the type of E1.E2 is T. **Otherwise, one of the following rules applies.**"

Comment: Oh I got it reversed. I read it 3 times thinking it had to be a reference to T. I'd put more context into answer though. I think it's important to have a whole rule. IMO this is it.

Comment: @luk32 I'm not sure how much more context I can give, the expression is simply invalid.

Comment: @user657267 fully true: the expression is invalid. This explains why  `decltype(a.A)` or typeid(a.A) are invalid.  However isn't the statement `A.a b;` a declaration and not an expression ?

Comment: @Christophe That would be a declaration with an invalid type specifier (I'm guessing you meant `a.A`, but it isn't important as neither is valid).

Answer (score 3):

The standard is talking about the type of the object that a variable represents.
You need to access the the scope of the class, not the variable.

And to access the members of the nested class from `U`, you need to create a member from that type, there are 2 ways to do that:

```
struct U
{
    struct A
    {
        static int v;
        int a;
    } VarNameForA;

    struct B
    {
       int b;
    };
    B VarNameOfB;
};
```

Use the scope operator `::` to access the types.

Here is how you do everything you tried:

```
U a;

typedef decltype(a) varType;
typedef varType::A  nestedType;

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(U::A).hash_code(); 
    struct U::A b;                        
    U u;
    u.VarNameForA.a = 5;
    u.VarNameOfB.b = 6;

    U::A::c = 3;                          

}
```

For members you use operator `dot (.)`, for types and statics you need to use the `scope ::` operator.

Comment: I think OP is aware of ::, but indicates the N3797::5.2.5/2 says otherwise.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think this answers the question. The question is not how to make the code work and properly define all the types. But why you cannot access type through `.`, while the given citations suggest you should be able to. Nested type is listed as a member, so even your answer suggest `.` should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

You try to use `a.A` as a type specifier.

The class member access rules (5.2.5) you refer to are valid only for **expressions** not for type specifiers and typenames (5/1:  "*An expression is a sequence of operators and operands that specifies a computation. An expression can result in a value and can cause side effects.*").

You have to look rules for **type specifiers** in section 7.1.6 of the standard. There is no use of operator `.` foreseen there.  The elaborated types (7.1.6.3) use a `::` to combine components on a typename.

The ***clang*** error message is more explicit than the one you get from your compiler:  "cannot use dot operator on a type").

By the way, your `U` is an empty structure (no data) with only definition of nested types.  This is why     `a.A.v = 5;` is also an error: there is no lvalue here which could be assigned.

Comment: So should `decltype(a.A)` work? I also could you point where is it said that 5.2.5 applies only to expressions?

Comment: Excellent question ! Std 7.1.6.2 defines decltype(expression) to be a type specifier.  But expressions are on values, not on types and a.A does not denote a value (*7.1.6.2.4:  If there is no such entity, (...) the program is ill-formed*)

Comment: The error message from clang for the decltype(a.A) is different from the previous ones.  it says "cannot refer to type member 'A' in 'U' with '.'" which suggest that the compiler applies in this case the rule mentioned by user657267.

Comment: Yeah, I also tested it on clang, and indeed it gives two distinct errors. So actually there are two different rules that forbid `variable.SubType` form. Gee. Thanks for explanation. I got the 5.2.5.4 rule, but you explained the 2nd one.